# How to create a table with postgresql in nodejs without an ORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

please I am trying to create a table with PostgreSQL using nodejs but I don't know how to go about it. I want the table to be created from the query without the use of an ORM

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement doesn't work ?

Comment: I don't know how to use it

Comment: You can use [pg](https://node-postgres.com/) package. [Here](https://gist.github.com/olawalejarvis/845692026adef05511ddbbc09ebe7ba3#file-db-js) is an example of table creation.

Comment: Okay for example in Laravel you use "php artisan migrate" which would then migrate your tables automatically for you in your db. How can you do that in express?

Answer (score 0):

Install ['pg' package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg).

```
const pg = require('pg');
const db = new pg.Pool({
 host: 'SERVER_IP',
 database: 'DB_NAME',
 user: 'USER',
 password: 'DB_PASS',
 port: '5432'
});
db.query(“CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, xzy VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
abc VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)”, (err, res) => {
console.log(err, res);
db.end();
});
```